# One Git repository, two working trees

Tags: git, msysgit

Is it possible to have two working trees (two different branches) on the same local repository (== shared .git directory)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably *alternates* could be helpful here to share one object store among multiple .git/-directories. Check for 'objects/info/alternates' at:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html

Comment: Yeah, http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html with the `--shared` option seems to be the key.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But you need to place the second branches workdir in a second directory, and hand manage the swap.

see [Git man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html):

```
--work-tree=<path>
Set the path to the working tree. It can be an absolute path or a path relative
to the current working directory. This can also be controlled by setting the 
GIT_WORK_TREE environment variable and the core.worktree configuration variable 
(see core.worktree in git-config(1) for a more detailed discussion).
```

This allows you to checkout to as many work tree/directories as you require, and check them back in in any order, against what ever branch you claim to have already checked out.

But don't be surprised if you make a few mistakes. It's a bit like running with scissors.

Comment: So the repository references the working-tree. Could it be done that the working-tree references its shared repository?

Comment: My description is for two working directories and one .git repo. One can direct git to look for its component parts in a range of places, rather than the defaults (see git man page again;-). However Git, at each command, works one-on-one with the paths and defaults you give. If colleagues need to work then they should have their own clone. A likely use-case for a WORK_DIR is a test or reference build running in slow time  off to one side from your fast fingers;-)

Answer (score 1):

No, you'd have to make two clones.

Comment: Are there some kind of "light-weight" clones?

Comment: @MikeL.: Clones of repos on the same file system will use hardlinks to Git object files to save space when possible.

Comment: @MikeL.: In which case, no, it wouldn't be lightweight.